# How to add star ratings and counter on all pages, not just shop page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to add average star ratings and a counter next to it showing how many reviews have been left. I have it working for just my shop page and I achieved that by adding this code to my themes(sober) functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'gkartikey_woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );
if ( ! function_exists( 'gkartikey_woocommerce_template_loop_rating' ) ) {

    /**
     * Display the average rating in the loop.
     */
    function gkartikey_woocommerce_template_loop_rating() {
        wc_get_template( 'loop/rating.php' );
    }
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_rating_html', function ( $html, $rating, $count ) {
    global $product;
    if ( $html && is_archive() && $product) {
        $html .= sprintf( '<span>%s</span>', $product->get_rating_count() );
    }

    return $html;
}, 10, 3 );
```

The problem is the counter doesn't show up on any other page like my home page where I have added products using Elementor.

**EXAMPLE PICTURE**: [Home Page Not Showing Counter Next To Stars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flb8h.jpg)

**EXAMPLE PICTURE**: [Shop Page Showing Counter Next To Stars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2hao.jpg)

Comment: What is Elementor? Perhaps you could link it, to clarify that.

Comment: https://elementor.com/ | Elementor is a page builder. @nyov

Comment: You're adding it into the page only if it's an archive. remove ````is_archive()```` see how that goes. Not tested, just logical.

Comment: Yeah, I tried removing **is_archive()** condition and the rating count shows on every page.